# Objective C: Multiple delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I am curious if and how to make a Controller be the delegate for two different objects.

Is this allowed or is this like multiple inheritance in Java?

Suppose I wanted to have one controller that responded to: `<UIAccelerometerDelegate>` and `<CLLocationManagerDelegate>`

Would the header file look like this?

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate> AND <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually, it works quite well. Declare your interface like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

and then implement the methods from both delegate interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 4):

As simple as that:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```