# Obj C - UITextViewDelegate incompatible type warning

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

Warning on the line with journalComment.delegate = self:  Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'JournalEntryViewController*'

journalComment is a textView.

I'm not sure what the warning is about, it should just say - warning: "newb at keyboard, go take some obj c classes."

Thank you for any help.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        // Hide keyboard when done key is pressed

        // define the area and location for the UITextView
        CGRect tfFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        journalComment = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:tfFrame];
        // make sure that it is editable
        journalComment.editable = YES;

        // add the controller as the delegate
        journalComment.delegate = self;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your class must conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, so in your .h file make it look like

```
@interface JournalEntryViewController : NSViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
{

...

}
```

Then the compiler will know that your class conforms to that protocol. Of course, you still need to implement the needed methods.

Comment: Can the interface be both a <UIScrollViewDelegate> and <UITextViewDelegate>?

Comment: nevermind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361148/objective-c-multiple-delegates

Answer (score 3):

The object from which you posted the sample code needs to implement the UITextViewDelegate protocol. To do that, your .h file should start with:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

In your .m file, you then need to implement your methods for the protocol (see [Apple Developer Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)). There aren't any which are required, but you may be interested in some of the delegate callbacks anyway.